# Make Apache ignore an IP range

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I want to block all traffic from China (due to hacking attempts and bandwidth wastage) and I'm currently doing that by htaccess:

```
    order allow,deny
allow from all

# China IP Address Blocks
deny from 1.80.0.0/13 1.92.0.0/14 1.192.0.0/13 1.202.0.0/15 1.204.0.0/14 14.144.0.0/12 14.208.0.0/12 23.80.54.0/24 23.104.141.0/24 23.105.14.0/24 27.8.0.0/13 27.16.0.0/12 27.36.0.0/14 27.40.0.0/13 27.50.128.0/17 27.54.192.0/18 27.106.128.0/18 27.115.0.0/17 27.148.0.0/14 27.152.0.0/13 27.184.0.0/13 36.32.0.0/14 36.248.0.0/14 42.96.128.0/17 42.120.0.0/15 58.16.0.0/15 58.20.0.0/16 58.21.0.0/16 58.22.0.0/15 58.34.0.0/16 58.37.0.0/16 58.38.0.0/16 58.40.0.0/16 58.42.0.0/16 58.44.0.0/14 58.48.0.0/13 58.56.0.0/15 58.58.0.0/16 58.59.0.0/17 58.60.0.0/14 58.68.128.0/17 58.82.0.0/15 58.100.0.0/15 58.208.0.0/12 58.242.0.0/15 58.246.0.0/15 58.248.0.0/13 59.32.0.0/12 59.51.0.0/16 59.52.0.0/14 59.56.0.0/13 59.72.0.0/16 59.108.0.0/15 59.172.0.0/14 60.0.0.0/13 60.11.0.0/16 60.12.0.0/16 60.24.0.0/13 60.160.0.0/11 60.194.0.0/15 60.208.0.0/13 60.216.0.0/15 60.220.0.0/14 61.4.64.0/20 61.4.80.0/22 61.4.176.0/20 61.48.0.0/13 61.128.0.0/10 61.135.0.0/16 61.136.0.0/18 61.139.0.0/16 61.145.73.208/28 61.147.0.0/16 61.150.0.0/16 61.152.0.0/16 61.154.0.0/16 61.160.0.0/16 61.162.0.0/15 61.164.0.0/16 61.175.0.0/16 61.177.0.0/16 61.179.0.0/16 61.183.0.0/16 61.184.0.0/16 61.185.219.232/29 61.187.0.0/16 61.188.0.0/16 61.232.0.0/14 61.236.0.0/15 61.240.0.0/14 101.64.0.0/13 101.72.0.0/14 101.76.0.0/15 101.80.0.0/12 103.253.4.0/22 106.112.0.0/13 110.6.0.0/15 110.51.0.0/16 110.52.0.0/15 110.80.0.0/13 110.88.0.0/14 110.96.0.0/11 110.173.0.0/19 110.173.32.0/20 110.173.64.0/18 110.192.0.0/11 110.240.0.0/12 111.0.0.0/10 111.72.0.0/13 111.121.0.0/16 111.128.0.0/11 111.160.0.0/13 111.172.0.0/14 111.176.0.0/13 111.228.0.0/14 112.0.0.0/10 112.64.0.0/14 112.80.0.0/12 112.100.0.0/14 112.111.0.0/16 112.122.0.0/15 112.224.0.0/11 113.0.0.0/13 113.8.0.0/15 113.12.0.0/14 113.16.0.0/15 113.18.0.0/16 113.62.0.0/15 113.64.0.0/10 113.128.0.0/15 113.136.0.0/13 113.194.0.0/15 113.204.0.0/14 114.28.0.0/16 114.80.0.0/12 114.96.0.0/13 114.104.0.0/14 114.112.0.0/14 112.109.128.0/17 114.216.0.0/13 114.224.0.0/11 115.24.0.0/15 115.28.0.0/15 115.32.0.0/14 115.48.0.0/12 115.84.0.0/18 115.100.0.0/15 115.148.0.0/14 115.152.0.0/15 115.168.0.0/14 115.212.0.0/16 115.230.0.0/16 115.236.96.0/23 115.236.136.0/22 115.239.228.0/22 116.1.0.0/16 116.2.0.0/15 116.4.0.0/14 116.8.0.0/14 116.16.0.0/12 116.52.0.0/14 116.76.0.0/15 116.90.80.0/20 116.112.0.0/14 116.128.0.0/10 116.204.0.0/15 116.208.0.0/14 116.224.0.0/12 116.254.128.0/18 117.8.0.0/13 117.21.0.0/16 117.22.0.0/15 117.24.0.0/13 117.32.0.0/13 117.40.0.0/14 117.44.0.0/15 117.79.224.0/20 117.80.0.0/12 117.136.0.0/13 118.26.0.0/16 118.72.0.0/13 118.112.0.0/13 118.120.0.0/14 118.132.0.0/14 118.144.0.0/14 118.180.0.0/14 118.186.0.0/15 118.192.0.0/16 118.248.0.0/13 119.0.0.0/13 119.8.0.0/16 119.10.0.0/17 119.18.192.0/20 119.36.0.0/16 119.57.0.0/16 119.60.0.0/16 119.88.0.0/14 119.96.0.0/13 119.112.0.0/13 119.120.0.0/13 119.128.0.0/12 119.144.0.0/14 119.164.0.0/14 119.176.0.0/12 119.233.0.0/16 120.0.0.0/12 120.24.0.0/14 120.32.0.0/13 120.40.0.0/14 120.68.0.0/14 120.80.0.0/13 120.192.0.0/10 121.0.16.0/20 121.8.0.0/13 121.16.0.0/12 121.32.0.0/14 121.60.0.0/14 121.76.0.0/15 121.196.0.0/14 121.204.0.0/14 121.224.0.0/12 122.10.128.0/17 122.51.128.0/17 122.64.0.0/11 122.119.0.0/16 122.136.0.0/13 122.156.0.0/14 122.188.0.0/14 122.192.0.0/14 122.198.0.0/16 122.200.64.0/18 122.224.0.0/12 123.4.0.0/14 123.8.0.0/13 123.52.0.0/14 123.64.0.0/11 123.97.128.0/17 123.100.0.0/19 123.112.0.0/12 123.128.0.0/13 123.138.0.0/15 123.150.0.0/15 123.152.0.0/13 123.164.0.0/14 123.180.0.0/14 123.184.0.0/14 123.196.0.0/15 123.232.0.0/14 123.249.0.0/16 124.42.64.0/18 124.64.0.0/15 124.67.0.0/16 124.73.0.0/16 124.114.0.0/15 124.126.0.0/15 124.128.0.0/13 124.160.0.0/15 124.162.0.0/16 124.163.0.0/16 124.192.0.0/15 124.200.0.0/13 124.226.0.0/15 124.228.0.0/14 124.236.0.0/14 124.240.0.0/17 124.240.128.0/18 124.248.0.0/17 125.36.0.0/14 125.40.0.0/13 125.64.0.0/12 125.79.0.0/16 125.80.0.0/13 125.88.0.0/13 125.104.0.0/13 125.112.0.0/12 125.210.0.0/15 140.224.0.0/16 140.237.0.0/16 140.246.0.0/16 140.249.0.0/16 159.226.0.0/16 171.34.0.0/15 171.36.0.0/14 171.40.0.0/13 175.0.0.0/12 175.16.0.0/13 175.24.0.0/14 175.30.0.0/15 175.42.0.0/15 175.44.0.0/16 175.46.0.0/15 175.48.0.0/12 175.64.0.0/11 175.102.0.0/16 175.106.128.0/17 175.146.0.0/15 175.148.0.0/14 175.152.0.0/14 175.160.0.0/12 175.178.0.0/16 175.184.128.0/18 175.185.0.0/16 175.186.0.0/15 175.188.0.0/14 180.76.0.0/16 180.96.0.0/11 180.136.0.0/13 180.152.0.0/13 180.208.0.0/15 182.18.0.0/17 182.32.0.0/12 182.88.0.0/14 182.112.0.0/12 182.128.0.0/12 183.0.0.0/10 183.64.0.0/13 183.129.0.0/16 183.148.0.0/16 183.160.0.0/12 183.184.0.0/13 183.192.0.0/11 192.34.109.224/28 192.74.224.0/19 198.2.203.64/28 198.2.212.160/28 202.43.144.0/22 202.46.32.0/19 202.66.0.0/16 202.75.208.0/20 202.96.0.0/12 202.111.160.0/19 202.112.0.0/14 202.117.0.0/16 202.165.176.0/20 202.196.80.0/20 203.69.0.0/16 203.86.0.0/18 203.86.64.0/19 203.93.0.0/16 203.169.160.0/19 203.171.224.0/20 210.5.0.0/19 210.14.128.0/19 210.21.0.0/16 210.32.0.0/14 210.51.0.0/16 210.52.0.0/15 210.77.0.0/16 210.192.96.0/19 211.76.96.0/20 211.78.208.0/20 211.86.144.0/20 211.90.0.0/15 211.92.0.0/14 211.96.0.0/13 211.136.0.0/13 211.144.12.0/22 211.144.96.0/19 211.144.160.0/20 211.147.0.0/16 211.152.14.0/24 211.154.64.0/19 211.154.128.0/19 211.155.24.0/22 211.157.32.0/19 211.160.0.0/13 211.233.70.0/24 218.0.0.0/11 218.56.0.0/13 218.64.0.0/11 218.84.0.0/14 218.88.0.0/13 218.96.0.0/14 218.102.0.0/16 218.104.0.0/14 218.108.0.0/15 218.194.80.0/20 218.200.0.0/13 218.240.0.0/13 219.128.0.0/11 219.154.0.0/15 219.223.192.0/18 219.232.0.0/16 219.234.80.0/20 219.235.0.0/16 220.112.0.0/16 220.154.0.0/15 220.160.0.0/11 220.181.0.0/16 220.191.0.0/16 220.192.0.0/12 220.228.70.0/24 220.242.0.0/15 220.248.0.0/14 220.250.0.0/19 220.252.0.0/16 221.0.0.0/12 221.122.0.0/15 221.176.0.0/13 221.192.0.0/14 221.200.0.0/14 221.204.0.0/15 221.206.0.0/16 221.207.0.0/16 221.208.0.0/12 221.212.0.0/15 221.214.0.0/15 221.216.0.0/13 221.224.0.0/13 221.228.0.0/14 221.232.0.0/13 222.32.0.0/11 222.64.0.0/12 222.80.0.0/12 222.132.0.0/14 222.136.0.0/13 222.168.0.0/13 222.172.222.0/24 222.176.0.0/13 222.184.0.0/13 222.200.0.0/16 222.208.0.0/13 222.219.0.0/16 222.220.0.0/15 222.240.0.0/13 223.4.0.0/14 223.64.0.0/11 223.144.0.0/12 223.240.0.0/13
```

This method will not serve anything from the root directory, but will send an HTML document with the 403 Forbidden error.
I don't want it to do that. I want it to ignore requests from China, and not serve anything back (empty response).How can I tell Apache to ignore requests from these IP ranges? I want it to drop all packets from China.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't block (With empty response - I am guessing when you said *empty response *, you mean no (403/404/etc)) from Apache. Instead, you can block them from firewall. I use iptables
This is just one example

`iptables -A INPUT -s 1.80.0.0/13 -j DROP`

I user a combination of iptables and fail2ban (highly recommend it)